# MySql 1045 When using --defaults-file

Tags: mysql, redhat, credentials

I am having a strange issue. I have MySql running on RHEL. I can logon to MySql with

```
mysql -uroot -pmyPassword
```

and it works fine. Also, when I try to execute a query from a .sh script as below it works fine

> `mysql --user=root --password=myPassword --host=localhost --port=3306 -se "SELECT 1 as testConnect" 2>&1>> $OUTPUT`

But when I store the userid and password in a msql.conf file as below

```
[clientroot] 
user=root
password=myPassword
```

and then change the line in the script as below

> `mysql --defaults-file=msql.conf --defaults-group-suffix=root -hlocalhost -P3306 -se "SELECT 1 as testConnect" 2>&1>> $OUTPUT`

When I run it, I get the error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am running the script with `sudo` and the config file is at the same directory as the script

I have permission `0600` on the config file.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Works for me in Windows. You can try adding `--print-defaults` after `mysql` in the command without option file, and after `--defaults-group-suffix=root` in the command with option file, and compare the results

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem and fix it.  I hope my answer below solves your problem. Thanks for asking this question actually, I didn't know this was possible and I'll probably use it myself. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It worked for me, but it was a bit of a 'tricky' fix that isn't shown in the actual documentation.  All you have to do is change

```
[clientroot] 
user=root
password=myPassword
```

to

```
[clientroot] 
user="root"
password="myPassword"
```

Basically just add the double quotes.

Then running your command:

```
mysql --defaults-file=msql.conf --defaults-group-suffix=root -hlocalhost -P3306 -se 
"SELECT 1 as testConnect" 2>&1>> $OUTPUT
```

Should work (it worked for me).

I discovered this by looking through an obscure part of the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) on something almost unrelated, so I don't blame everyone for missing it.

Comment: Wow!!!! You just made my day.. Thank you very much.. that s it.. it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Like I mentioned above, it was helpful for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Options files are not meant for auto-login credentials.

Try this:

```
export MYSQL_PWD=myPassword
```

And try to connect using the `root` user.

---

Note that this approach is "insecure", but so is the basic idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Bohemian. But this is not solving my problem. I  tried setting the variable MYSQL_PWD, still gives the same error. Also when I try running  mysql --defaults-file=msql.conf --print-defaults it gives the below output. "mysql would have been started with the following arguments:
--user=root --password=*****". It I am sure it is reading the file and reading the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

When your goal is to not use the password in scripts or on command line, may I suggest a different approach?
You can create a file with the login credentials encrypted and use that for logging in.

Here's an example:
Create the file with

```
mysql_config_editor --set-login-path=local --host=localhost --user=localuser --password
```

This creates the file `~/.mylogin.cnf`. You can now login with

```
mysql --login-path=local
```

`local` is a name you can specify, btw.

Here's another plus: You can also create different files for different projects. For example, I sometimes create files for certain scripts. I put the `.mylogin.cnf` in the same folder as the script and use it like this in the script:

```
RESULT=($(MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE=./.mylogin.cnf mysql --login-path=$HOST -B --skip-column-names -e "SELECT whatever FROM whatever"))
```

- Read more about mysql_config_editor [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html).

Comment: Thanks fancyPants for taking time. Problem is these scripts are given to us by another product vendor and I do not want to go in and modify all the scripts given by them. It will be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Okay, I'll not delete the answer though, it might still be usefull for someone else.